# How can I configure OWD and Sharing sets to allow Customer Community user to see all cases for their account and any child accounts?

Tags: customer-community, sharing-sets

I have a business requirement to allow Customer Community user to see all cases for their account and any child accounts?  Is there a way to create 2 sharing sets, or some other option to grant both types of access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Salesforce, this is not supported with the standard Customer Community License. However, they do offer a Customer Community Plus License that is supposed to support manual sharing.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this using the Community Settings Sharing Sets as long as the Customer Community user is a contact on the parent account. Was it Salesforce support who told you that? I would actually like to know if there is a document somewhere I can view that shows that. It would help us out a lot. Thanks. 
The setting you want on the sharing set is 
[image]